# How to remove an item that is pulled away from it's list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

here is a simple question.  I have a 'ul' which i have made sortable via jquery-ui's sortable() function.  I want to remove elements when they are dragged off the list.  The way i have it implemented works in the sense that when i drag an element away from the list it gets removed, but it also gets removed when i just rearrange the list.  How do i achieve the behavior i am looking for without this unintended behavior.  Below is all the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" href="jquery-ui/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#sortme').sortable({
            out: function(event, ui){
                ui.item.remove();
            }
        });
        $('#sortme').disableSelection();
    });
    </script>

    <style>
    li{
        list-style-type: none;
        width: 200px;
        height: 50px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        text-align: center;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding-top: 15px;
    }
    </style>
    <title> jqui sort test </title>

</head>
<body>
    <ul id='sortme'>
        <li>0</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could try to use a variable to check if the items you are dragging is dragged out of its parent container.

You can use the **over** and **out** events of the jQuery UI sortable to assign the value for this variable and then execute the removal of the dragged item on the **beforeStop** event.

here is a demo of what I have come up with: http://jsfiddle.net/drewP/m7VJq/1/

let me know if it works for you.

Comment: This was bloody brilliant! Saved the day Drew! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are more than one correct way to do that but if i had to do it I would probably use a wrapper element as droppable. Why not main site container, the almighty #wrapper! Bind to `drop` event of the droppable and remove the item completely. It won't stay in sortable either.