# jquery remove from droppable when dragged out

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have implemented jQuery's draggable and droppable based on the example [shopping cart demo](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#shopping-cart). I would like to be able to remove the `<li>` from the droppable when you drag it out of the droppable. I thought this might have something to do with the [droppable out event](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-out) but the ui parameter is empty. Does anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a complete working solution, not completly tested, you should still debug it maybe: 
{reassign draggable to dropped element to fired drop out event}
{you should reassign droppable too!}

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RR6z5/1/embedded/result/)

[EDITABLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RR6z5/1)

```
$(function () {
    $("#catalog").accordion();
    $("#catalog li").draggable({
        appendTo: "body",
        helper: "clone"
    });
    $("#cart ol").droppable({
        out: function (event, ui) {
            var self = ui;
            ui.helper.off('mouseup').on('mouseup', function () {
                $(this).remove();
                self.draggable.remove();
            });
        },
        activeClass: "ui-state-default",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.draggable.is('.dropped')) return false;
            $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
            $("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this).draggable({
                appendTo: "body",
                helper: "clone"
            }).addClass('dropped');
        }
    }).sortable({
        items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
        sort: function () {
            // gets added unintentionally by droppable interacting with sortable
            // using connectWithSortable fixes this, but doesn't allow you to customize active/hoverClass options
            $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
        }
    });


});
```

Comment: this is great.. I guess the ui parameter isn't empty after all. One thing though, it seems the out method fires as soon as the mouse exits the droppable container.. is there an easy way to make it wait until the mouse button is released?

Comment: Just checked and the new solution isn't working correctly, but should give you the idea

Comment: This is a perfect answer !

Comment: One thing i noticed, if you remove `<li class="placeholder">Add your items here</li>`, you can't add anymore. Is that by design?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to change the list style.
Something like this should work:

```
.ui-droppable .ui-sortable ol { list-style: none outside none; }
```

or better yet

```
#cart ol { list-style: none outside none; }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not just trying to hide the bullet. I actually want to remove the element from the droppable container when it is dragged out.

Comment: maybe adding `ui.draggable.remove();` after `$("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this);` See demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmnca/)

Answer (score 0):

A.Wolff's solution got me on the right track, but using the sortable.out function via Drew's solution from this post: 
[How to remove an item that is pulled away from it's list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403422/how-to-remove-an-item-that-is-pulled-away-from-its-list)
is a better solution

```js
$(function () {
    var removeIntent = false;
    
    $("#catalog").accordion();
    $("#catalog li").draggable({
        appendTo: "body",
        helper: "clone"
    });
    $("#cart ol").droppable({
        activeClass: "ui-state-default",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
            $("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this);
        }
    }).sortable({
        items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
        sort: function () {
            // gets added unintentionally by droppable interacting with sortable
            // using connectWithSortable fixes this, but doesn't allow you to customize active/hoverClass options
            $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
        },
        over: function () {
            removeIntent = false;
        },
        out: function () {
            removeIntent = true;
        },
        beforeStop: function (event, ui) {
            if(removeIntent == true){
                ui.item.remove();   
            }
        }
    });


});
```