# "Out" event in a sortable is never triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-trigger

I have a sortable (made of nested `<div></div>`) on my webpage. I would like that an item dragged out of the sortable be removed from the sortable.
But I can't get the "out" event to be triggered.

Here is my JS (inspired from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403422/jquery-sortable-how-to-remove-an-item-that-is-pulled-away-from-its-list)):

```
    $(function(){
        var removeIntent = false;
        $('#selectedTags').sortable({
            over: function () {
                removeIntent = false;
                console.log("over: "+removeIntent);
            },
            out: function () {
                removeIntent = true;
                console.log("over: "+removeIntent);
            },
            beforeStop: function (event, ui) {
                console.log("over: "+removeIntent);
                if(removeIntent){
                    ui.item.remove();   
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

You will find my jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/D2qnQ/).

All help is welcome.

Edit: If I convert my divs to a `<ul></ul>` it then works as planned. Any explanations there ? I would like to keep the `<div></div>` though as I need the sortable to be horizontal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checked your fiddle; it seems that the css

```
#selectedTags > div {float: left;
}
```

is what is actually causing the out not to be triggered. Just a pointer!

Comment: Yes. See http://jsfiddle.net/D2qnQ/1/ The only change that I did was to remove the styling.

Comment: OK but now the sortable is not horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix : just use an horizontal list format instead of focusing on the `<div></div>` stuff.

I still don't know why the `out` event won't work for divs though.

SO way to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145181/how-to-make-a-html-list-appear-horizontally-instead-of-vertically-using-css-only)

```
    #menu ul{
      list-style: none;
    }

    #menu li{
      display: inline;
    }
```