# How to determine if a child element is outside the containing ancestor?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have list items which are inside a container `div`. The structure looks as follows:

```
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I am using jQuery sortable to swap list items, as shown [here](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/).

I want to determine if the list item is dragged outside of the containing `div`, and if so, delete it.

What I have been trying to do is use `offset()` to determine the distance of list item from `div`, but it gives me inconsistent results:

```
$( ".sortable" ).sortable({
    revert: true,
    update: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log("difference: " + (parseInt($(ui.item).offset().top,10) - parseInt($("#importer-container").offset().top,10)) );
    }
});
```

Sometimes it says 1. Sometimes it says 26. The container `div` has a scroll bar if that matters.

How can I determine if a child is outside parent?

Comment: out side parent u mean the dom structure or the viewable part?

Comment: Outside parent meaning the list item is dragged outside the div with id of container.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403422

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Sortable: how to remove an item that is pulled away from it's list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403422/jquery-sortable-how-to-remove-an-item-that-is-pulled-away-from-its-list)

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".sortable" ).sortable({
    revert: true,
    update: function( event, ui ) {
        if (ui.item.closest("#container").length) {
            // inside container
        } else {
            // outside container
        }
    }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: It does not seem to work. The else block never runs even when dragging list item outside div.

Comment: I need to be able to determine position when mouse out event, because the jquery sortable will snap the element back into the list.

Comment: @DanStayntouch Try changing `ui.item.closest("#container")` to `ui.item.closest("#container").length` as `ui.item.closest("#container")` will always return true